# Strange product names in analytics

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, google-analytics

For some reason my product names looks really strange in Google analytics, when fetching data from my Magento2 installation.

For instance GEAR\u0020H\u00E5ndmixer\u0020Olivia\u00201.0\u0020Rosa when the real name in magento (and also in the database) is GEAR Håndmixer Olivia 1.0 Rosa

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: known bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13350 - fixed in 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Your product isn't UTF-8 friendly, try adding following setting to your Google Analytics

```
ga('set', 'encoding', 'UTF-16'); // or UTF-8
```

More details can be found at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#encoding

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adnan, but my site should be UTF-8?
I got the following in my header
<meta charset="utf-8">

Also page titles seems to be encoded correctly.. just the products that's all weird for some reason.

Comment: Did a little more digging, and seems like the name is wrong even before being passed to analytics.
in the ga.php file, it calls this function $this->escapeJs($item->getName())
and the return here, also contains the weird product name. Maybe I can replace this call with a better one?

Comment: This function 'escapeJS' is normally escapes unprintable (non utf8) characters, give it a try and replace this call with better one.

Comment: @Michael yes you are right but I am talking about GA, sometimes we have to tell GA that treat all values with different encoding, you may try both solution, first replace escapeJS with suitable one or add encoding in GA.